# Google in-app billing v4 TrivialDriveSample is very complicated can it be simpler?

Tags: android-inapp-purchase

I have been writing Android apps for a few years now. I have now to implement in-app billing. I think this TrivialDriveSample is too complex already, and the syntax is overwhelming.
My case is simple, one consumable product, if the sale goes through he gets the report! The purchase is consummated immediately or not at all.

In-App billing is already complex, with products, bank accounts, keys in local.properties, does not work in debug etc etc. The example programmers use complex syntax with viewModelProvider.Factory etc. I'm sure it makes for elegant structure and reliable execution but it's hard to follow if you have not met these syntactical elements before. Surely part of the purpose of an example is to help the user.

So to return to my question. Where can I find a straightforward example of in-app billing that I can lift and adapt to my local needs?